# How can I add a class to this version of a dropdownlistFor?

Tags: asp.net, dropdownlistfor

There seem to be many different ways to create a dropdownlistFor. Viewbags etc.

I've been trying some different versions but always have problem adding all the "attributes" I need. It can't be possible that I should have to choose whether I want to use Distinct() OR add a class to my dropdownlistFor.

Please have a look at this, how would you go about adding a class to this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CatDropTemp,
                                Model.Categories.Distinct().Select(kat => new SelectListItem { Text = kat, Value = kat }), "----Choose----")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703670%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of the `DropDownListFor`. It has all the params you are using plus additional one, `object htmlAttributes`. Basically that is how you assign arbitrary html attributes to the resulting tag. So if you wanted something like `someAttribute`, you would pass `new object { someAttribute = "value" }`.

Now `class` is a bit different since this is a key word in C#. So for class you should precede it is `@`. Like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.CatDropTemp,
    Model.Categories.Distinct().Select(kat => new SelectListItem { Text = kat, Value = kat }),
    "----Choose----",
    new object { @class = "theClass" })
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! This one goes into the bookmarks =)